# What's the current best practice for Using Google Maps API within React/Meteor

Tags: meteor, google-maps-api-3, reactjs

I've been running into issues getting React and Google Maps API to play together nicely. Currently I'm rendering the google maps API script tag to the page, and calling the googleMap InitMap function through the tag - per instructions in the Maps documentation.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#The_Hello_World_of_Google_Maps_v3

This gives me a grey square with no error messages? Are there any best practices for this? I've searched extensively on google but can't find a single widespread pattern. I'm using React with Meteor 1.3.

Comment: I would recommend looking for a package that has this integration. Did you see this one on Google? https://github.com/dburles/meteor-google-maps-react-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cloned [this project](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-google-maps-react-example) and ran it - it's running just fine.

You can find it from here: https://github.com/dburles/meteor-google-maps#examples

I did try updating the project to `Meteor 1.3` and it coughed a little bit - but I think you should be able to figure out how to add this to your project just by browsing the source code.

Good luck buddy!

Comment: Thanks buddy! This works great

Comment: Anytime, good luck with Meteor!